# VS Code Not Recognizing New Conda Environment

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

I am fairly new to Python Programming and have been working hard to get setup properly with my local environment.

I am running Mac OS 10.15.4 and the latest version of VS Code, Python 3.8.4 and the mini conda distribution.

When I open VS Code, it recognizes SOME of the environments I've created from my terminal using conda commands but new environments created using terminal are not being recognized in VS Code.

I've reviewed the documentation online on the VS Code Website and believe I have set things up properly. Is there another way for VS Code to recognize my newly created Python Environment?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that any conda environment you create you specified a Python version. if you don't then there isn't a Python version that gets installed and the Python extension won't recognize it. See the [docs on how the extension detects environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environments-and-terminal-windows) for details.

Comment: Hey Brett! Thanks for getting back to me.

In my various environments I have specified the python type, but I will review the documentation you reference so I can understand things a bit more clearly. I need to update my question above to be more specific, but even for the environments that ARE recognized by VS Code, I’m unable to switch between them easily. Is this a normal feature of VS Code? Ex: I create a workspace, open a .py file in that workspace after selecting a conda environment and then am unable to switch to a new environment even using any of the activate commands in terminal.

Comment: It might be easier to quit VS Code, activate the conda environment, and then launch VS Code from that activated environment. But terminal activation from within VS Code won't affect this.